# Inspect js variables in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've searched extensively but am only more confused than when I started.  I have a very simple html+js webpage... html loads my js script, and the js script of course has lots of variables defined and used.

In Chrome Dev Tools I'm looking for a simple way of browsing all the variables defined and used in my js script, and their current values (with the execution paused).

I've looked in the `Scope` panel of the `Sources` tab, which looks promising, but I can't see my js variables in the `Local` part, and the `Global` part has an almost infinite tree of elements that I don't know where to start looking for variables specifically used in my js.

Code snippets below... so I'd like to find a convenient way of inspecting variables and their values, like `data` for example:

`index.html:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

`main.js:`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var data = [];

    (function init() {
        $('#dragme').hide();
        var str = 'hello';
        data.push('sample');
        myFn(data, str);
        // more stuff here...
    });

});
```

Comment: Global variables are generally best avoided anyway. Don't use them and the problem goes away.

Comment: what is scope of your variables? are they global vars or they belong to an object. May be posting some parts of your code can help.

Comment: Code snippets added... and @Quentin what do you mean by that?

Comment: You can add the keyword `debugger` anywhere in your code to make devtools pause script execution at that line, assuming code execution runs to that line, and you can hover over the variables to see the values of them or do many other things while stopped at that point of code execution.

Answer (score 6):

The [Google Chrome Breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) are what you were looking for. Just click at the line number you want to pause at and the execution stops next time the line is executed. You can then look into each variable in the current state.

Comment: I used to see the var values with the value in orange background on every variable in source code, but now its not there, any ideas how to turn it back on?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper I am sorry, I believe I don't quite understood your problem. When I hover over variables, I see their value. There is also a display for variables in the current scope in (I believe) the new chrome.